# Getting rack error Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware, rack-middleware

I'm trying to build my rack based ruby app, and I'm still new here, I'm using ruby 1.9.2 -p180

in my config.ru file I have:

```
require "rack"
require "./my_app.rb"
require "./auth.rb"

use Auth
run MyApp.new
```

Now main problem with Middleware Auth, simply, I want it to not continue MyApp if there were less than 2 params for the request and just print out something ( just for testing ) :

```
class Auth

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)     
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.params.count < 2
        ["200",{"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello World"]]
        puts 'Working .. '
    else 
        @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I run my rack app :

```
rackup -s thin config.ru
```

And try to get the results :

```
curl http://localhost:9292/
```

I keep getting the following error :

```
Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer
/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:19:in `assert'
/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:425:in `check_status'
```

Of course if I run it with production mode I will not get this error.

Any help would be appreciated here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an integer for the status:

```
[200,{"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello World"]]
```

Instead of:

```
["200",{"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello World"]]
```